# which size to compile linux kernel

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, kernel, virtualbox

I am compiling linux kernel on an `Ubuntu` machine in a VM, my host being `OSX`. I began with a 8Go VM, then 15 Go, and now 21 Go, and I am still running out of space errors. What correct size should I forecast ? is there a way to control it with some options when running the compilation

Answer (score 1):

I used around 29GB for a recent Ubuntu 4.8 Yakkety kernel build for x86-64, so I'd recommend at least 35GB for source, generated objects and deb packages.

Comment: I used to be amazed when building Chromium required ~10-15 GB years ago... Then I looked around a realised that's peanuts. :/

Comment: Wow! I am very surprised. I only compile a git clone of the mainline kernel, from kernel.org, using the Ubuntu kernel configuration file. My entire structure, after a compile verses clean, is 4,829,016,493 bytes.

Comment: Oh, I always compile without debug stuff (I run `scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO`), because then a clean compile takes about 26 minutes instead of 59 minutes, and an incremental compile takes maybe 5 minutes. If I compile with debug stuff then my git directory plus .deb files is about 22 Gigabytes.

Comment: The default ubuntu configs build in a lot of kernel features and large amount of modules, so it's always a lot of object code.